# Issued kill -9 -1, centos not working

Tags: centos, ssh, boot

created user in centos and edited nano /etc/passwd and edited created user as user:x:0:0::/home/user:/bin/bash and logged as that created user and issued kill -9 -1, from then on words my server not working

please help me what to do.
reboot doen't help on cloud server. i don't have ssh access from then onward issuing the command

Comment: Why did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't edit your /etc/passwd & /etc/group directly, please read up on what system tools to use (for adding users, changing password, modifying a user account, etc...)

Also, I suspect you did more damage than just the `kill -9 -1` (what where you trying to do with that!?),
so I suggest you start with a fresh install again and carry on learning the hard way.

Sometimes starting afresh is better than trying to fix a mess :-)